# Jquery scroll to a div tag

Tags: jquery

I use the following in order scrolling to top.
How could i edit it so the top is set by a div tag?

```
var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(function() {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: @strakastrouks: You mean, you don't want to scroll to the absolute top of the page, but to a specific top where a specific DIV is placed?

Comment: Yeap! That is correct. But my English are awful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `.offset()` to get the correct position value like:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#div').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

`.offset` returns the current position of an element relative to the document.

References: [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/), [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: Use `.offset()` instead which gives position relative to the document as `scrollTop` also works relative to the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is nice, as well:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo